# Converting a temporary character array to a string in D

Tags: d

I'm learning D language (I know C++ well)... I want to do some Windows specific stuff so I wrote this just to try out the API:

```
import core.sys.windows.windows;
import std.stdio;

string name()
{
    char buffer[100];
    uint size = 100;

    GetComputerNameA(&buffer[0], &size);

    return buffer;
}

void main()
{
    writeln(name());
}
```

I get in my return statement:

```
test.d(11): Error: cannot implicitly convert expression (buffer) of type char[100] to string
```

Ok, in C++ it would call the constructor to make a string. It says implicit so lets cast it with a C style cast: `return (string)buffer;`.

```
test.d(11): Error: C style cast illegal, use cast(string)buffer
```

Ah ok, I remember, different syntax.

```
return cast(string)buffer;
```

Now it compiles but I just get garbage.

I assume that is is because it's storing a pointer in the string to the temporary buffer. I don't want to do this, I want to copy the characters into a string but annoyingly I can't seem to find how to do this?

So questions:

1. How do I construct an actual string from a char array that allocates storage properly? (Copies the characters)
2. Allocating a buffer of a random size like this and converting to a string seems ugly. Is there a proper way to do this in D? (I'm talking about the general question, not specifically this API just in case there is another API to get the computer name).
3. If either of those are answered in a manual where should I have looked to find details?

Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: Can you try to check the actual value of `buffer` before it's converted, because the conversion should not fail.

Comment: The conversion works... if i print it in the function... it fails if I return string, presumably because it still refers to the temporary buffer.

Comment: @Bauss, no, it shouldn't. In fact 2.068 aborts compilation with: `Error: escaping reference to local variable buffer`.

Comment: @sigod the original code compiles on mine without any error or warning using 2.068 on windows...

Comment: @jcode, http://imgur.com/fo0NPxW

Comment: Also, D's syntax for arrays: `type[...] name`.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the proposed answers, don't forget to accept one

Answer (score 8):

I think you need:

```
string name()
{
   char buffer[100];
   uint size = 100;

   GetComputerNameA(buffer.ptr, &size);

   return buffer[0 .. size].idup;
}
```

Comment: But it is still ignore  ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW & GetLastError. Correct code should check that `size` is less then buffer.length, and allocates new bigger buffer otherwise

Comment: Yes of course, my original sample was just the shortest sample I could write to demonstrate my question. Its not intended to be complete.

Answer (score 6):

`buffer.idup` is the standard way to get an immutable copy.  For this case, since you want a dynamically-sized `string` (and recall that `string` is really just shorthand for `immutable(char)[]`), you want `buffer[0..size].idup`, using D's array slicing.

See http://dlang.org/arrays.html for more information.

(This is a bit of a nitpick, but you may want to use `buffer.ptr` instead of `&buffer[0]`, mostly for readability's sake.)

Comment: Excellent thanks, That works. Ok the information is clear now. It can be hard to know what to look for in the documentation when you are new to a language.

And thanks for the nitpick! That's exactly the kind of advice I need when I'm new to D :)