# Nul terminated strings in character array

Tags: d

This simple D program :-

```
import std.stdio;
import core.sys.windows.windows;

void main()
{
    char data[100];
    uint size = 100;
    GetComputerNameA(&data[0], &size);
    writeln("Name is:", data, "with size of ", size);
}
```

Prints the name of the computer and then the uninitialized contents of the rest of the character array. It's not treating data as a nul terminated string in writeln.

That's fine, and I can see a number of ways to deal with this.
But what is the "correct" idiomatic way to deal with this in D? (Either in printing, allocating the memory, converting to a proper string etc?)

**edit:** 
I just realized that I asked a very similar looking question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220621/converting-a-temporary-character-array-to-a-string-in-d) but I guess it's not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std.string.fromStringz`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_string.html#.fromStringz):

```
import std.stdio;
import std.string;
import core.sys.windows.windows;

void main()
{
    char[100] data;
    uint size = data.length;
    GetComputerNameA(&data[0], &size);
    data[$-1] = 0; // ensure null-terminated
    writeln("Name is: ", data.ptr.fromStringz);
}
```

In this case, you may want to use `GetComputerName`'s second parameter, though, e.g.: `data[0..size]`. Make sure to also check the function's return value, in case the buffer is not large enough.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for and somehow didn't find :)